# A claim about number field and galois group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I saw the claim that if $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a number field with $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=n$ such that $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ doesn't contain any element of order $n$, then for any prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, $p$ can't be inert. I wonder why it is true.

Comment: Hint: What is the Galois group of $\mathcal O_K/p\mathcal O_K$ over $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Wojowu  The Galois group...of a quotient ring?

Comment: @DonAntonio It's a field if $p$ is inert.

Comment: @Wojowu That's fine, yet what is a "Galois Group" of a field, or ring, over another field? I suppose you have something in mind, but I just don't know what...

Comment: @DonAntonio You can naturally view $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ as a subfield of $\mathcal O_K/p\mathcal O_K$ and you look at the Galois group of this extension. Not sure what more there is to say.

Comment: @Wojowu Well, that clears up things a little : for a field *extension* $\;L/K\;$ , we can talk of its Galois group Aut$(L/K)\;$ of all $\;K\,-$ endomorphism of $\;L\;$ (Though some could probably tell that "Galois" group fits only in case the extension is Galois...) Anyway, now it is clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio Glad to have it clarified; I have myself encountered the phrase "Galois group of $L$ over $K$" to mean the Galois group of (the field extension) $L/K$ many times, thought it would be clear what I meant.

Comment: @Wojowu And I'd agree with that use. Not so long ago there was a little discussion here about the proper use of the name "Galois Group". As usual, I don't think some definite overall agreement was reached...:)

Comment: @Wojowu why can we naturally view ℤ/pℤ as a subfield of $O_k/pO_k$?

Comment: @Danny For every $n\in\mathbb Z$ we can look at its image in $\mathcal O_K/p\mathcal O_K$. Kernel of this map contains $p\mathbb Z$, so we can view this as a map from $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ to $\mathcal O_K/p\mathcal O_K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wojowu's comment pretty clearly gives the right direction, but I will elaborate for the sake of completeness. Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field of degree $n$, and let $p$ be a rational prime which is inert in $\mathscr{O}_K$. Then Dedekind's factorization criterion implies that $\mathscr{O}_K/p\mathscr{O}_K$ is a degree $n$ extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$, which has Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}((\mathscr{O}_K/p\mathscr{O}_K)/\mathbb{F}_p)=C_n$ cyclic of order $n$, generated by the Frobenius element $\mathrm{Frob}_p=\{x\mapsto x^p\}$. But we know that the decomposition group $D_p$ (equal in the inert case to all of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$) surjects onto $\mathrm{Gal}((\mathscr{O}_K/p\mathscr{O}_K)/\mathbb{F}_p)=C_n$, and any element of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ mapping to the generator $\mathrm{Frob}_p$ must have order divisible by $n$, so $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ must have an element of order $n$.